# Compare 3 Products from same table with product name

Tags: php, jquery, json, pivot

```
CREATE TABLE spec_property
    (`spm_id` int, `spec_value` varchar(11),  `product_name` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO spec_property
    (`spm_id`, `spec_value`, `product_name`)
VALUES
    (6, 'android', 'phone 1'),
    (7, '4GB', 'phone 1'),
    (7, '2GB', 'phone 2'),
    (7, '2GB', 'phone 3'),
    (11, '8mp', 'phone 1')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d38db

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| spm_id | col1                | col 2               | col 3               |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    Name| phone1              | phone2              |phone3               |
|      6 | android             |                     |                     |
|      7 | 4GB                 | 2GB                 | 2GB                 |
|     11 | 8mp                 |                     |                     |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I need product compare page using php. I am able to convert row into column from mysql fetch query.  The problem is the result is missing "product_name" for title.

Comment: why dont you provide us with the convertion code in order to modify it?

Comment: I dont get your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pure mysql (not ideal but gives the result you want)

```
SELECT "Name" as spm_id, "phone1" as col1 , "phone2" as col2 ,"phone3" as col3

UNION

SELECT spm_id, GROUP_CONCAT(col1) as col1, GROUP_CONCAT(col2) as col2, GROUP_CONCAT(col3) as col3 FROM (
    SELECT spm_id, 
        IF(product_name = "phone 1", spec_value,NULL) as col1 ,
        IF(product_name = "phone 2", spec_value,NULL) as col2,
        IF(product_name = "phone 3", spec_value,NULL) as col3
    FROM spec_property
) AS tmp
GROUP BY spm_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc7c89/2/0
I think you can do a better work (more extensible) in php, with some basic queries and arrays.

Comment: thanks for your query **TOMAS**.... Really useful to me. since i looked for php  array script which will take less processing time. Anyway thanks once again for your answer